# What file lets me change the directories linked to through the places menu

Tags: 14.04, filesystem

I'm sure I've edited this before but I've searched around for answers and I can't seem to find what the file was. (ex to change the location of the pictures link under the places menu to somewhere other than home/pictures)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you are looking for is `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` in your home directory.

You can modify the entry by changing `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/Picture"` to `XDG_PICTURES_DIR="/<your_pictures_directory>"`.

The same thing goes for any other such directory.